# return response from a function while the other codes are running .netcore

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have this function :

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("See/{OID}")]
    public IActionResult See([FromRoute]long OID)
    {
        //time ham bayad chek bshe
        orders order = _context.orders.FirstOrDefault(e => e.OID == OID);

        lastViewed lv = _context.lastViewed.FirstOrDefault(e => e.UID.ToString() == User.Identity.Name);

        if (DateTime.Compare(lv.sentTime.AddSeconds(order.seconds), GetUTCDateTime()) < 0)
            return Content("1");

        unViewed UV = _context.unViewed.FirstOrDefault(e => e.UID.ToString() == User.Identity.Name && e.OID == OID);

        if (UV != null)            
            _context.unViewed.Remove(UV);            

        coins coin = _context.coins.FirstOrDefault(e => e.UID.ToString() == User.Identity.Name);            

        if (order.type > 50)
            coin.Coin += order.seconds * 8;
        else
            coin.Coin += order.seconds;

        order.view--;

        if (order.view == 0)
        {
            var uv = _context.unViewed.Where(e => e.OID == OID);
            foreach (unViewed uvv in uv)
                _context.unViewed.Remove(uvv);

            pastOrders po = new pastOrders
            {
                link = order.link,
                OID = order.OID,
                UID = order.UID
            };


            _context.pastOrders.Add(po);
            _context.orders.Remove(order);
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return showlink();
    }
```

the showlink() function is an IActionResult.the showlink() is fully independent from other codes.
my question is here how to first response the showlink() to user and after that response, run the other codes ?
thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule the rest of the code to run on a separate thread. Note, though, that this is not entirely safe as you are not checking to see if the thread properly executed. In order to do that, you would need to add other checks to your code along with a way to be notified if something fails. Adopting an asynchronous model is a big undertaking and is the long term solution.

However, the following should unblock you for this particular case:

```
var result = showlink();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    // Rest of your code that needs to run in the background.
});
return result;
```